# How can i store multiple .ico files into a .DLL file

Tags: dll

How can i store multiple .ico files into a .DLL file that can be opened and read from just like SHELL32.dll.

i am using it for a few .ico files that i am making that a few of my friends might want to use also, and it would be much nicer to use a .dll like SHELL32.dll.

i have:

- office 2007 (the built in VB)
- Visual studio 2010 express
- i might still have some old verstion
  of BASIC (command prompt programming)

i have windows 7 home premium 64bit

Comment: i have tried making a class library project, adding the .icos and making them compile as embedded resources, that does not work. that is, unless i'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the limited resource editing capabilities of VS2010 express, as I remember it was painful to add version information to resources under C++ Express Edition.
My quick research resulted in GConvert to be a suitable program that is unfortunately not free.

Comment: unfortunately, i have no funding for this, as i am broke so i cannot buy applications.

Comment: Maybe it is okay for you to use .icl-files (Icon Libraries). IcoFX, which is a freeware program, can create icl-files for you from icons you specify.

Comment: i have icoFX, i did not know it could do that (in fact,i made the icons from using icoFX)

Comment: this does in fact work, icoFX, while not making a .DLL, does make a file that is openable like SHELL32.dll

Comment: you must use the tools -> resource editor tool to add your icons and save all the icons to an icl.

Comment: .icl files are .dll files. just rename them.

Answer (score 2):

Create a DLL project in VS10. Edit resources. Add as many icons as you want.

Comment: by edit resources, do you mean go to the "my project" file and go to resources? i have tried that.

Comment: You must create a C++ dll project. Then adding icons will do. IcoFX as noted before is must easier and more useful.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio should have a resource compiler that can bundle icons into exe or dll formats. You could probably use a wizard of some kind to create a new dll project, and then just stuff that with the icons.

Visual Studio Express might not be as capable. As an alternative, if you are up for it, MinGW has a resource editor, and MinGW is free.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that very easily using resource compiler tools like Resource Hacker or Resource Tuner. You can save them in .dll or .res formats

Comment: Please provide extra information to make your answer more useful, e.g. links